# How do I terminate a program in Python?

Tags: python

This is my project description:

Write a program that displays the following menu:

> 1) Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
>   2) Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit
>
> Enter 1, 2, or 0 to exit:

In the case of options 1 and 2, the program should then prompt the user for the temperature, perform the conversion, and output the result. Then the program should re-display the menu. When option 0 is chosen, the program should exit.

Here is what I have so far:

```
a = raw_input("1) Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius \n2) Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit \nEnter 1, 2, or 0 to exit: ")

x = raw_input("Enter degree: ")

y = float((x - 32) / 1.8)

x = raw_input("Enter degree: ")

z = float((x + 32) * 1.8)

if a == 1:
    print(y)

if a == 2:
    print(z)
```

How can I terminate this program? Where else am I messing up?

Comment: Homework?  If so, you should tag it as such.

Comment: I'd feel like a jerk if I didn't point out that your z equation should read:

z = float((x / 1.8) + 32)

Answer (score 1):

- Get rid of the second `x = raw_input(...` line. You don't need it.
- Calculate `y` right before you `print` it, inside the `if` block. No point doing math the user didn't want.
- Same for `z`: calculate it right before you need it.
- Put this after the `a = raw_input(...` line:

Code:

```
if a == 0:
    import sys
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Just an addition: No one has mentionned the loop so far. Of course all that has to be in a `while True:` loop. And then you also can use `break` to leave that loop and terminate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. convert a and x to int.

   ```
   a = int(raw_input("1) Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius \n2) Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit \nEnter 1, 2, or 0 to exit: "))

   x = int(raw_input("Enter degree: "))
   ```
2. Do the calculations inside if blocks.
3. Also, get rid of the second `x = raw_input("Enter degree: ")`
4. And as said in above answer, you can use the `sys.exit(0)`